# How Can I refactor this DB Query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Disclaimer: I'm new to Rails.

What I'm trying to do is this in the long form:

```
user = Spree::User.find(2)
cart = Spree::Order.where(state: "cart", user_id: user.id)
line_item = Spree::LineItem.where(order_id: cart.last.id).map { |order| order.variant_id}
variant = Spree::Variant.find(line_item).map { |order| order.product_id }
Spree::Product.find(variant).map { |product| product.name }
```

What happens is it goes into the DB, finds the user, gets an order where their state is in cart. Then goes and finds its line item. Goes over to find the "variant" data to find out what products are included. Then over to the products page to tell me all products in a users cart.

This looks ugly and garjumbled. You wouldn't happen to know a way to refactor it and not do so much querying?

Comment: The keyword "has many" is popping up everywhere. I think I'll take note of this... I should have mentioned that Spree is an open source ecommerce framework for ruby on rails.

Comment: Which version of Spree are you using? I can't find any documentation and/or code for Spree::User...

Comment: Its probably because I'm working with a customized build right now.

Comment: BenMorganIO aha. Then you should see the code for `Spree::User` and see if it has `has_one order` or `has_many orders`. In the latter case, you'll need to use `order = user.orders.where(state: "cart")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Spree Order States](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/order_states.html), it's not that you have multiple orders in different states, just one order that could be in one particular state.

It really depends on `Spree::User`. I can't find documentation and/or source for `Spree::User`, but mentions to a certain `LegacyUser`.
Since in the comments you mentioned you have a custom build, you need to check the actual code for `Spree::User` and see if a user can have one or many orders, and if there's already a method for selecting cart state orders.

So if `Spree::User` has one order:

```
order = user.order
order.variants.map(&:name)
```

Else:

```
order = user.orders.where(state: "cart")
order.variants.map(&:name)
```

There could be a method to get the order you need from the user in the code.

Comment: For some clarity on what a "variant" is. Basically you have a product. A product is a  perhaps a tshirt. A variant belongs to the product and would list different "variants" of that tshirt: red tshirt, green tshirt, blue tshirt, you get the idea. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm going through it making the changes. Starting from top to bottom. In our models, we don't specify that a user has many orders. Nor anything you've got here. I'll add them.

Comment: Do I need a belongs to user in order?

Comment: I actually don't know if there's one "cart" per user. Its difficult to tell actually. So I just ask for a list of orders where the state is cart and belongs to a certain user... I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: Testing it in my terminal and it doesn't seem to work. I'll keep testing it though to figure out where everything goes. Thank you for the help. Much appreciated!